React Native jest config module map errror
Faced with an issue after update from Expo 47 to 50 in my Bare project with tests and modulemapper.
Issue text from logs:
FAIL  src/features/Loan/Create/Lend/components/Checked/index.test.tsx
● Test suite failed to run
Configuration error:

Could not locate module  mapped as:
/Users/a.trofimenko/Documents/Work/ReactNativeProjects/zirtue-app/src/$1.

Tests running sucessfully




Downgrade to "jest-expo": "^49.0.0" solved an issue
